# Suggestions on how to fix this tricky problem in Java

Tags: java

In the given array in Java, `[766-09-9090, 766-09-9090, 877-90-9090, 877-90-9090, "S", "T", "U"]`

> How could we obtain a new array with values like this : 
>             [766-09-9090, 877-90-9090, 877-90-9090, 766-90-9090, "S", "T", "U"]
>                             Note : No changes on non SSN values like "S", "T, "U"

This is my first stab but I am not getting the results I am looking for. Any suggestion would be appreciate

```
public static modifyArray(List<String> arrays) {
    List<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean matchedFound = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < arrays.size(); index++) {
        if (arrays.get(index).length() == 9 && isValidSSN(arrays.get(index))) {

            String nextMatchingSsn = getNextDistinctSsn(arrays);

            System.out.println("Next Distinct SSN IS : " + nextMatchingSsn);

            if (nextMatchingSsn != "") {

                String[] pair = nextMatchingSsn.split(":");

                if (pair.length == 2) {
                    Integer key = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);
                    String ssn = pair[0];

                    swap(arrays.toArray(), index, key);

                }

            }
            newArray.add(nextMatchingSsn);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Non Matching " + arrays.get(index));
            newArray.add(arrays.get(index));
        }

    }
}

private static boolean isValidSSN(String s) {
    if (s.length() != 9) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("An SSN length must be 9");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("SSN must have only digits.");
        }
    return (true);
}

private static String getNextDistinctSsn(List<String> ssns) {

    String firstDiffSsn = "";
    String currentSsn = "";

    for (int index = 0; index < ssns.size(); index++) {

        if (!currentSsn.equals(ssns.get(index)) && currentSsn != "") {

            firstDiffSsn = ssns.get(index);

            return firstDiffSsn + ":" + index;
        } else {
            currentSsn = ssns.get(index);
        }
    }

    return firstDiffSsn;`enter code here`
}

public static final <T> void swap (T[] a, int i, int j) {
      T t = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = t;
    }
```

This is my first stab but I am not getting the results I am looking for. Any suggestion would be appreciated. So basically, if I have to write a unit test my expected result would look something like this:

```
public void validateResult(){


}
```

Comment: how did you get from the first array to the second array?

Comment: You need to explain the *requirements* completely.  What is the logic for deciding when to switch the elements' order?

Comment: Hi Stephen, the requirement is pretty easy, basically, an array should not contain the 2 contiguous elements with the same values. For example, given an array with 4 elements say ["900-90-9090", "900-90-9090", "800-09-7887", "900-800-09-7887"] should have output like this : ["900-90-9090", "800-09-7887",  "900-90-9090", "900-800-09-7887"]

Comment: Put it into the question!.  Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56511542/edit) button.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a number of problems.

- Your code is creating a new list (called `newArray` !?!) and populating it, but then not using it.
- Your code is splitting SSNs on a `:` character, but the input data has no `:` characters.
- Your SSN validation method will throw an unchecked exception if it encounters something that is not a valid SSN, but your code *expects* it to return `false` in that scenario.
- This is wrong: `currentSsn != ""`.  Do not use `==` or `!=` to compare strings.  You are liable to get an incorrect result.

And so on.